# How to generate n dimensional random variables in a specific range in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to generate uniform random variables in the range of `[-10,10]` of various dimensions in python. Numbers of 2,3,4,5.... dimension.

I tried random.uniform(-10,10), but that is only one dimensional. I do not know how to do it for n-dimension.
By 2 dimension I mean,

```
[[1 2], [3 4]...]
```

Comment: what do you mean by various dimensions

Comment: @DannyBeckett  hope the edit helps

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `numpy` is tagged, you can use the random functions in `numpy.random`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.uniform(-10,10)
7.435802529756465
>>> np.random.uniform(-10,10,size=(2,3))
array([[-0.40137954, -1.01510912, -0.41982265],
       [-8.12662965,  6.25365713, -8.093228  ]])
>>> np.random.uniform(-10,10,size=(1,5,1))
array([[[-3.31802611],
        [ 4.60814984],
        [ 1.82297046],
        [-0.47581074],
        [-8.1432223 ]]])
```

and modify the `size` parameter to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

use `random.uniform`

```
import random

random_variable_in_range_of_minus_ten_and_plus_ten = random.uniform(-10, 10)
```

note that it is between (by design) [-10, 10) not [-10, 10]

now for n-dimension, I don't really get what you meant but suppose it being a vector with n numbers, you can :

```
def n_dimensional_random_variables(n, lbound=-10, rbound=10):
  return [random.uniform(lbound, rbound) for i in xrange(n)]
```

Comment: How to do this for n dimension?